# A way to set property of array contents?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, undefined

I've got an inventory script that I'm using to create a readout of the players inventory from an array. I need to set a .amount property, but I'm getting some undefined errors when I try to set them like this. I can't use sets or hashmaps. Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

I'm using NaN only to debug the code at the moment.

```
    //This is already defined as an array, just a shortcut.//
    var inv = state.history[0].variables.player.inventory;
    inv[i].amount = 0;

    //Do this for every item in the inventory.//
    for (var i = 0; i < inv.length; i++) {

        //If the inventory item is Apple should resolve to ...inventory.Apple.amount.//
        var q = inv[i].amount;

        //If we find a duplicate in the array, just count and keep going.//
        if (inv[i] == inv[i-1]){
            q = (q + 1);

        //If the item is the last one or unique, print the item on the inventory screen.//
        } else {
            q = (q + 1);
            alert(inv[i] + " " + q.NaN);
            new Wikifier(place, inv[i] + " " + q.NaN + "<br>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Java !== JavaScript :)

Comment: Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get i before it is defined in the loop, put it after:

```
//This is already defined as an array, just a shortcut.//
var inv = state.history[0].variables.player.inventory;

//Do this for every item in the inventory.//
for (var i = 0; i < inv.length; i++) {
    inv[i].amount = 0;

    //If the inventory item is Apple should resolve to ...inventory.Apple.amount.//
    var q = inv[i].amount;

    //If we find a duplicate in the array, just count and keep going.//
    if (inv[i] == inv[i-1]){
        q = (q + 1);

    //If the item is the last one or unique, print the item on the inventory screen.//
    } else {
        q = (q + 1);
        alert(inv[i] + " " + q.NaN);
        new Wikifier(place, inv[i] + " " + q.NaN + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, should have asked it that way. I did this as suggested, but inv[i].amount is still coming up as undefined.

http://imgur.com/ga0Ggvr